# Counterexample for showing $u_n>0,$ $\lim u_n=0$ does not imply $\sum u_n<\infty$ other than $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

It is known that for $u_n>0,$ $\lim u_n=0$ does not imply $\sum u_n<\infty.$ The well-known counterexample is that of harmonic series $\sum\frac{1}{n^p}.$

However so far that is the only counterexample I have came through.

I am interested in knowing some more counterexamples. Please tell me a few.

Comment: you might try $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ or $\frac{1}{\log n}$

Answer (score 3):

You have, in fact, 
$$\sum \frac 1 {n^{p}}$$
diverges for $ p \leq 1$, so you have a bunch of examples there.

Answer (score 1):

One famous, and perhaps surprising, reply:

$$\sum_{p \text{ prime}} \frac{1}{p}$$

It grows like $\log \log n$, and shows that there are "lots of primes" heuristically, since they form enough of the harmonic series to still diverge.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The simple (symmetric) random random walk -- you return to the starting position with probability one, so with the number of moves until first return given by random variable $T$, the complementary CDF has the sequence $u_n =Pr\{T \gt n\}\to 0$ but $\sum_n u_n= \sum_n Pr\{T \gt n\} = E\big[T\big] = \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

How about $u_n=\frac 1 n$ for  $n$ even and $\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ ( or $\frac  1 {2^{n}})$ for $n$ odd?